# SpringMVC ErrorHandling with JavaScript UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-mvc, kendo-ui

I have a SpringMVC 3.2 service with a HTML/endoUI UI that I am unable to return messages to.  It would seem that the RequestAttributes that I populate are not visible to the Javascript.  All the examples I have seen for SpringMVC error handling use either html or jsp redirects.

Here is a sample:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping( "/officeSignUp" )
public class OfficeSignUpController
..
@RequestMapping( value = "/stepOne", method = RequestMethod.POST )
@ResponseBody
public String officeCreationStepOne( @Valid @ModelAttribute( "officeSetup" ) OfficeSetup officeSetup,
        BindingResult result, Model model, RedirectAttributes attributes ) {
    String results;

    results = newOfficeValidator.validateStepOne( officeSetup, result );

    NewCustomerSignup newCustSignup = newOfficeValidator.validateNewOwner( officeSetup );

    model.addAttribute( newCustomerSignupRepository.save( newCustSignup ) );

    return results;

}
```

My validator is:

@Component
public class NewOfficeValidator {

```
public String validateStepOne( OfficeSetup officeSetup, BindingResult result ) {

List<String> errors = new ArrayList<String>();
if (result.hasErrors()) {
    for (ObjectError error : result.getAllErrors()) {
        errors.add( error.getDefaultMessage() );
    }
    errors.add( "redirect: " + VIEW_STEP_ONE );
           // RuntimeException with a list of strings in it
    throw new OfficeSetupException( errors, "Validation in StepOne" );
  }


    return VIEW_STEP_TWO;
}
```

And in my BaseController I catch the exception, retrieve the error messages and use them:

```
@ExceptionHandler
@ResponseStatus( HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST )
@ResponseBody
public ErrorMessage handleOfficeSetupException( OfficeSetupException ex ) {

    List<String> errors = ex.getErrors();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (String error : errors) {
        sb.append( error );
    }
        // this is just a bean with a list of Strings
    return new ErrorMessage( errors );
}
```

When an exception is thrown, instead of a json or string response, I get a tomcat html message which contains:

```
<h1>HTTP Status 400 - Received OfficeSetupException </h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u>Received OfficeSetupException </u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect (Received OfficeSetupException ).</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>Apache Tomcat/7.0.27</h3></body></html>
```

and then in the javascript :

```
if(stepString == "Step 2"){ click on step 2
       if(viewModelStepOne.validateStepOne(s) == true){ client side validation
           viewModelStepOne.saveStepOne(s);if above validation passes, send request to server,
       if(serverValidationFailed){if server returns error, do not move to step 2
            s.preventDefault();
       }else{ move to step 
          this.disable(this.tabGroup.children("li").eq(2),true);
          this.enable(this.tabGroup.children("li").eq(3),true);
       }
    }else{ s.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

So ultimately my question is this:  what is the best way to return validation or other error messages from spring mvc to a javascript front end?  I am trying to use JSON for my responses, so I would expect the ErrorMessage to be returned as such.

Comment: I noticed you use model.addAttribute(...) in a handler method annotated with @ResponseBody. Why is that? (model is used to access data in view, but you are not using a view).

Answer (score 1):

In my projects I do as you described - throw an exception and catch it with the @ExceptionHandler. But you don't need to return just a string message. Create your own exception class that can take Map or List of errors as arguments (or whatever else you want to use as an errors model). When an error happens populate your custom execption (let's call it RequestException) with the errors and then throw it. Errors will be stored in your exeception instance. In @ExceptionHandler for your RequestException fetch the errors from the exception object and return then to frontend in a way convenient to you.

Comment: I have updated my post with the @ExceptionHandler and actual error message being received on the UI.  For some reason, the actual exception appears to be thrown from there, which should not be the case

Comment: Can you verify that the handleOfficeSetupException is indeed called and executed after the exception is thrown in validateStepOne? Also, does OfficeSignUpController class extend the BaseController? (I assume yes, but it is not visible in the posted code)

Comment: Yes, I can step thru and see the BaseController handle the exception, which then parses the errors and returns the ErrorMessage.  The UI receives the 400 (confirmed via FireBug) and the Tomcat error.

Comment: When you POST the request is Accept header in request set to "application/json"? When validation doesn't fail in officeCreationStepOne do you get result normally (e.g. does returning objects with @ResponseBody and receiving json works for you elsewhere in the app)? Could you turn log level to TRACE and see if there are any exceptions in the logs?

Comment: I am not sure I follow.  I dont explicitly declare what I am receiving or sending.  I am receiving a form submission, and that seems to work fine.  In other places I am returning JSON without declaring it as "produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE".  But this is the only time I am actually trying to handle returning a response from my BaseController.

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved it by adding the "@JsonAutoDetect" to my Exception.   I am using Java Config so the following appears to handle the HTTP response code and return a JSON response.

```
@JsonAutoDetect( fieldVisibility = Visibility.DEFAULT, getterVisibility = Visibility.DEFAULT, isGetterVisibility = Visibility.DEFAULT )
public class OfficeSetupException extends RuntimeException {

    private List<String> errors;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1L;

    public OfficeSetupException( List<String> errors, String message ) {
        super( message );
        this.errors = errors;
    }

    public List<String> getErrors() {
        return errors;
    }

}
```